# Definition p-value and find p-value in practice

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, uniform-distribution, extreme-value, definition

I have a problem that I can't solution. Let $\mathbf{X}=\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}\sim\mathrm{Uniform}(0,\theta)$ and we have $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ and $H_1:\theta>\theta_0$. We reject the $H_0$ when $X_{(n)}>c$. Find $\mathbf{p\textbf{-}value}$.
I know that $\mathbf{p\textbf{-}value}=\mathbb{Pr}_{\theta_0}(T(\mathbf{X})>T(\mathbf{x}))$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is the observed value of $\mathbf{X}$, but next I don't know what is observed value and how to find $T(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: What is $X_{(n)}$? I'm assuming this is some sort of test statistic that is a function of $\mathbf X$.

Comment: $X_{(n)}=\max\mathbf{X}$

Comment: You might be interested into this previous question about the [tank problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421771/solution-to-german-tank-problem).

Comment: If you know what $T(\mathbf{X})$ is, then $T(\mathbf{x})$ is naturally determined (and is then treated as a non-random value).  Can you find $T(\mathbf{X})$ for this problem?

Comment: Uniform distributions are fodder for many textbook questions, so searching for [related posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniform+theta+statistic+estimate) turns up promising hits.